# Time in hours and minutes... please suggest me

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

for login_details  am calculating the time between login and logout but its calculating only in minutes,  want in hours and minutes. please help me and  written the code as below

```
   <table>
  <%count = 1%>
      <%@login_info.each do |l| %>
       <tr>
        <td><%= count%></td>
        <td><%=l.user.name%></td>
        <td><%=Location.find(l.location_id).name%></td>
        <td><%=showdatetime(l.login_time)%></td>
        <td><%=showdatetime(l.logout_time)%></td>

     <td> <%= time=(l.logout_time.minus_with_coercion(l.login_time)/60)%>minutes</td>  


        </tr>
     <%count = count+1%>          
      <%end%>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out this code

```
       <%count = 1%>
         <%@login_info.each do |l| %>
       <tr>
        <td><%= count%></td>
        <td><%=l.user.name%></td>
        <td><%=Location.find(l.location_id).name%></td>
        <td><%=showdatetime(l.login_time)%></td>
        <td><%=showdatetime(l.logout_time)%></td>

          <td>
     <%seconds = l.logout_time.to_i - l.login_time.to_i%>
     <% days = seconds / 86400%>
   hours = seconds / 3600%>
 <%minutes = (seconds - (hours * 3600)) / 60%>
       <%= hours.to_s + "hr" + minutes.to_s + "min"%></td>  


        </tr>
     <%count = count+1%>          
      <%end%>
```

Comment: thanks it working correctly if i need seconds what i have to do

Comment: add this  <%= hours.to_s + "hr" + minutes.to_s + "min" + seconds.to_s%>

Answer (score 0):

Check out [distance_of_time_in_words](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words).